# How to hide a button from a horizontal stack view in swift

Tags: ios, swift, button, stackview

I want to hide one of the button from a horizontal stack view. First I tried to do

```
button1.isHidden = true
```

That didn't hide the button. Then I tried

```
horizontakStackView.removeArrangedSubview(button1)
button1.removeFromSuperview()
```

but still the button was showing in the screen. I was only able to hide the entire stackview. How can hide specific elements inside a stackview? Please help me

Comment: Please show how you created it in ib/code

Comment: I tested, it works normally. I created a stack view, with 2 buttons; action on first button toggles isHidden for the second button. Please show full code.

Comment: I guess button1 is not pointing to the view you think it is?

Comment: Hope button1 is pointing to proper outlet from nib which you trying to hide.